# What is a Turn in the context of the Stronghold?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Some things in the Stronghold, such as taxes or resource generating buildings, depend on "turns". What is a turn in this context? How do I go from one turn to the next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Near as I've observed so far, Stronghold "turns" are not tied to units of game time, but rather to the completion of quests (and possibly tasks, also). It's not clear if the completion of one quest/task produces an advancement of one turn, or if some quests cause more than one turn advancement (or perhaps each quest update causes a turn advancement).

Presumably they're implemented like this to avoid the possibility of resting over and over to generate effectively-infinite cashflow through tax collection.

Comment: After having played for a while, it seems that turn advancement is based on some kind of parameter on the quests. Major quests can advance several during their completion, while simpler tasks sometimes do not advance a turn at all.